# How to use _user_mail_notify with a defined language

Tags: 7, users, emails

as the title say, I would like to know how to use `_user_mail_notify` with a specified language.

According to the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) the third parameter should be the one that override [user_preferred_language()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_preferred_language/7) but when I specify it the language used is always the one returned by l[anguage_default()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_default/7).

My code is pretty simple:

```
_user_mail_notify($op, $account, $mail_lang);
```

Where:

`$op` is `'register_admin_created'` as the account is created programmatically.
`$account` is the return value of [user_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7)
`$mail_lang` is an object selected from the array returned by [language_list('enabled')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/7) (as I understood it should be).

I don't know if I'm using it wrong or there is a bug in the function, anyone used it with a custom language and can help me understand?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally understood and overcome the issue, in order to send emails in a different (enabled) language multilingual features must be enabled for the emails.

To enable the multilingual features there are just few steps:

1. The module "User mail translation" has to be enabled
2. From the Variable configuration (admin/config/regional/i18n/variable) you have to select the tab "User emails" and then check the email types you want available in a different language
3. From the account setting page (admin/config/people/accounts) then you select the language (in the very first box of the page) and add the translation for the related email templates (just scroll down)

After this 3 steps you will be able to send emails in all the enabled (and translated) languages in your site.